# Calculate standard deviation for each variable given in a vector

Tags: r, standard-deviation

When I have a vector of strings, and each string corresponds to a variable in a dataframe, how can I easily receive a vector of corresponding standard deviations? Is there something better than a loop?

Below an example using `mtcars`:

```
attach(mtcars)
string_vector <- ("mpg", "cyl", "disp")
```

I know how to calculate the standard deviations

```
sd(mpg)
# 6.026948
sd(cyl)
# 1.785922
sd(disp)
# 123.9387
```

What I want in the end is

```
sd_vector <- c(sd(mpg), sd(cyl), sd(disp))
sd_vector
#    6.026948   1.785922 123.938694
```

Comment: `apply(mtcars[, string_vector ], 2, sd)`? Don't use `attach`.

Comment: `attach` was just for illustration purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sapply`:

```
> string_vector <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")
> sapply(mtcars[string_vector], sd)
       mpg        cyl       disp 
  6.026948   1.785922 123.938694
```

Comment: `sapply` or `vapply` might be preferable for the op.

Comment: What would be the difference for me?

Comment: As you can see above, `sapply` returns an atomic vector. `vapply` would also return an atomic vector i.e. try `vapply(mtcars[string_vector], sd, numeric(1))`; 
`lapply` would return a list. For more info check out Hadley’s excellent lapply-sapply-vapply description here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals-loop